# FTP transport hangs while reading bunch of files with specific threading profile

Tags: java, multithreading, ftp, mule

If use ftp connector with defined threading profile for reading multiple files then the connector get stuck under certain conditions. Also it stops polling ftp for new files.

Example of threading profile:

```
<receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="5" maxBufferSize="5" threadWaitTimeout="-1" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT" />
```

If FTP has 10 (maxThreadsActive + maxBufferSize = 10) or more files then only 4 of them will be processed and 6 will still remain on the ftp. Polling also won't occur any more.

Workaround
Define threading profile for ftp connector and set number of active threads and max buffer size so that maxThreadsActive + maxBufferSize is greater then the number of simultaneously fetched files.

Is it a bug or predicted behavior?

Comment: Wondering if you ever came to a solution for this? Having roughly the same issue. Much appreciated.